# Prove That the Two Intervals have the Same Cardinality

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Needing to prove that $|[0,1]| = |(4,7)|$.

I know by the Schroeder-Bernstein Theorem: if $f: A \rightarrow B$ is one to one then $|A| \le |B|$ and if $f: A \rightarrow B$ is onto then $|A| \ge |B|$ then we can conclude $|A| = |B|$.

I know $(4,7)$ is a open interval or can be view as a point, but what exactly is $[0,1]$ in this context? I know it's a intervals where it is closed to $0$ and $1$.

Don't how to show this is one-to-one or onto without have a formula. I was thinking I could do slope intercept form and get a equation that I could show one-to-one and onto, but I don't think I can do that $[0,1]$.

Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: $(4,7)$ here denotes the *open interval* between $4$ and $7$.

Comment: I see; I added it to my question. I know it can be described as a point. Is the question hinting at, they both have a interval that is uncountably infinite?

Comment: For one part, consider $[0,1]\to (4,7),\ x\mapsto x+5$.

Comment: Are you saying, “every number in the interval $[0,1]$ maps to something in $(4,7)$; we can see this with input $x$ maps to something inside the interval $(4,7)$ by using $x +5$?” Sorry, I’m not fully understanding the notation.

Comment: The map I gave is one-to-one, therefore $|[0,1]|\le|(4,7)|$. Give another one-to-one mapping $(4,7)\to[0,1]$ to prove $|(4,7)|\le|[0,1]|$ and finish by Schroeder-Bernstein.

Comment: Thank you! That really helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Another way:**
If $g(x) := \tfrac13 x - \tfrac43$ for $x \in (4,7)$, then $g$ is a one-to-one function from $(4,7)$ onto $(0,1)$. Now, if we define
$$\begin{align}
f : (0,1) & \to [0,1] \\
\tfrac12 & \mapsto 0 \\
\tfrac13 & \mapsto 1 \\
\tfrac14 & \mapsto \tfrac12 \\
\tfrac15 & \mapsto \tfrac13 \\
& \ \, \, \vdots \\
x & \mapsto x \quad \small \textrm{if $x$ cannot be written as $\tfrac1n$ for some integer $n \geq 2$,}
\end{align}$$
then $f \circ g$ is a one-to-one function from $(4,7)$ onto $[0,1]$.